# Pager starts to change pages back and forth when clicking page links fast

Tags: gwt, pager, repeat

I have a Pager extended from AbstractPager in which every time on range or row count changed I recreate NavLinks contained in it so pager looks like this:
1 2 3 … N-1 N N+1 … M-2 M-1 M
My algorithm works fine but when I start clicking on links fast (like really furiously) by the time one RangeChange event is performing (CellTable to which my pager is attached shows spin trying to fetch data on given page) there's already another ones coming to the EventBus. It results in changing current page back and forth in an infinite loop.
I tried to make paging links enabled only when current page is competely fetched by using Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred and .scheduleFinally but with no luck.
My temporary solution is to enable paging links after 500 ms by using Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(), but I want to know how to get the exact moment of data on the current page being fully fetched.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem you need to hang LoadingChangeEvent.Handler on your CellTable, check if data is fully loaded and inform pager about it so pager can activate it's NavLinks:

```
pager.setDisplay(cellTable);
cellTable.addLoadingStateChangeHandler(new LoadingStateChangeEvent.Handler() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStateChanged(LoadingStateChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getLoadingState() == LoadingStateChangeEvent.LoadingState.LOADED) {
            pager.activateNavLinks();
        };
    }
});
```

There's no way to do it internally in your pager since setDisplay() accepts HasRows and addLoadingStateChangeHandler() is in AbstractHasData (AbstractHasData implements HasData, HasData implements HasRows).